# About "ubuntu" name copyrights

Tags: lubuntu

I just wanna know if the name of "Ubuntu" has copyrights and can't be used in the name of an album of music for example.

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  Most of us here are users, and don't work for Canonical (the copyright holder of Ubuntu), so we're probably not the people to ask. You could go to https://www.ubuntu.com/legal or https://www.ubuntu.com/licensing  (*thought its more about software*)

Comment: Agreed with @guiverc but maybe the Trademarks might shed more light  https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

Comment: Copyright doesn't apply to a name. Trademark does. IP rights like Trademarks depend on your jurisdiction (where you are in the World).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to being the name of an operating system, ubuntu is also a dictionary word. You can't prohibit a dictionary word from being used as a song title or an album title.

Trademark infringement is the unauthorized use of a trademark or service mark on or in connection with goods and/or services in a manner that is likely to cause confusion, deception, or mistake about the source of the goods and/or services. Using a dictionary word as a song title or an album title is not generally considered to be trademark infringement by law.

u·bun·tu
ˌo͝oˈbo͝on(t)o͞o/
noun
*South African*

> a quality that includes the essential human virtues; compassion and humanity.<sup>**[*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ubuntu)**</sup>